# Transfer / Serialization of Python ML trained models (Cloud) to C++ (Mobile App)

Tags: python, c++, opencv, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Let's say there are two trained ML models for image classification purposes: SVC, Cascade. This implementation is done using Python: scikit-learn, OpenCV, pandas.

Initially the classification is executed as a part of Python web application running in the cloud:

1. OpenCV: detection features using Cascade Classifiers.
2. scikit-learn: recognition features using SVC.

Now there is a need to do the same image classification for mobile apps: Android, iOS. So the classifier should be executed inside the mobile apps.

Mobile apps will use OpenCV C++ library.

Question:
What's the most optimal way to transfer the trained models to the mobile apps?

Now I'm thinking about the following options:

1. Cascade Classifiers - to use YAML export and import of OpenCV. Will it work fine between Python and C++ versions of OpenCV?
2. SVC - both OpenCV and scikit-learn are based on LibSVM. Is there are way to save / load SVM model data?

Thanks in advance.

-- Oleg